# Change instance return value without using Instance variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can someone give me the best possible solution for this,

I have a `class`

```
Class A

  def a
    return "a" if @logic
    return "b"
  end

  def change_logic
    @logic = true
  end

end
```

In my solution, I should be able to do

```
object = A.new
object.change_logic
object.a #print "a"
```

or

```
object = A.new
object.a #print "b"
```

To implement this I created the method `change_logic` & it will change `@logic` instance variable.

But I need to implement this without having a instance variable like `@logic`

What will be the best way to do it??

Comment: question - why would you want to do it without having a instance variable like `@logic`?

Comment: A variable is *exactly* the right solution for this. Why don't you want to use one? Also, what *precisely* do you mean by "without having a instance variable like `@logic`"? Is it enough to just rename the instance variable? Would a closure closing over a local variable count as "like an instance variable"? Would a class variable with a map from instances to values count as "like an instance variable"? Can you give a *precise*, unambiguous, objective, exact, complete specification of what *exactly* "like an instance variable" means?

Comment: Why can't you use an instance variable? do you still want to call a `change_logic` method to modify `a` return value? I can't imagine the reason behind that requirement

Comment: I would like to have a different approach rather than having a boolean type instance variable & a method to change that variable. May be `delegates` or `attr_writer`??

Comment: attr_writer is just a shorthand way of creating an instance variable and accesssor method and delegates is just exposing an interface of another object. Either way you end up with an instance variable and some mechanism for setting it.

Comment: Thanks, I would have `attr_writer` then. I makes my code more cleaner

Comment: Is the change intended to be temporary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to change what's returned conditionally but you don't want the condition at instance level then the method needs to be informed of what that condition is. For example,

```
Class A
  def a(logic = false)
    logic ? 'a' : 'b'
  end    
end
```

then it would be invoked instead as:

```
object = A.new
object.a(true) #print "a"
```

or

```
object = A.new
object.a #print "b"
```

Comment: You've introduced [a boolean parameter code smell](https://github.com/troessner/reek/blob/master/docs/Boolean-Parameter.md).

Comment: @yzalavin not sure I actually agree with that ... according to that documentation it states 'Make the decision what method to call in the initial caller of hit_the_switch' ... ie you are simply moving the if else block outside the method to somewhere else ... just exactly why does it reek to let the method itself decide what to do rather than the caller?

Comment: _"moving the if else block outside the method to somewhere else"_ – you could also say "to where it belongs". The method (`a`) doesn't decide what to do, the caller does by passing `true` or `false`. The caller could therefore just as well invoke different methods (e.g. `object.b` instead of `object.a`). That would simplify `A` and probably make the code easier to follow.

Comment: I really think it depends on the context to be honest ... and I agree the contrived solution isn't the best but neither was the question ... it was unclear just exactly where or how the condition would be determined. As it turns out using an instance variable is fine but what the OP actually wanted was to make his code look cleaner. I'm interested how would you suggest removing the code smell now that the condition is determined from an instance variable that may be set outside the scope of the calling method?